# Separating unique and duplicate entries between two dataframes

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I load a file into a dataframe and before saving the dataframe in my table, I want to check if any rows in the dataframe already exists in the table.

e.g. 
My table has following schema

```
A  B  C 
1  2  3 
2  4  5
```

My dataframe has following

```
A  B  C
1  2  5 
2  3  5
```

Definition of unique is combination of A & B column. So in the above example, the duplicate entry is ( 1, 2, 5) since both dataframe and the table has (1, 2) as a value for A & B. And Unique record is (2,3,5) since table doesn't have (2,3) as value for A & B.

So the output I want is two dataframe. One that contains unique i.e. (2,3,5) and one that contains duplicate i.e (1,2,5).

Let's call my current dataframe as df1 & the dataframe after loading the table as df2.

Comment: This can be solved with joins. Did you try anything?

Comment: I was trying to do the join but didn't know about except feature. I was attempting to do all in single operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, join the dataframes in order to obtain duplicate rows, for example:

```
val df2alias = "df2"
val resultColumns = df2.columns.map(colName => s"$df2alias.$colName")

val duplicates = df1.join(df2.as(df2alias))
  .where(df1("A") === df2("A") && df1("B") === df2("B"))
  .select(resultColumns.head, resultColumns.tail:_*)
```

`duplicates` contains only `(1, 2, 5)` row.

Second, use `duplicates` to obtain unique rows:

```
val uniques = df2.except(duplicates)
```

`uniques` contains only `(2, 3, 5)` row.

Comment: I see that I'm not able to say .select(df2.columns) instead of .select(df2("A"), df2("B"), df2("C")). Does it only accept array of columns?

Comment: @Peter: I changed the answer to take all columns from df2 in resulting dataframe.